DC-DC Buck Boost Layout Feedback
Need feedback and review on PCB Layout for DC-DC Converter,
IC Used: LM5118 and TPS54531DDA
The PCB chosen is 4-Layer Stack-Up, Size 95 x 120,
Vin: 24V
there are 3 Voltage output:
V1: 12V, 5A
V2: 12V, 5A
V3: 19V, 6A
LM5118, PCB

PCB LAYOUT, LM5118

LM5118 Schematics,


No gate resistors?

The thermal reliefs are to thin to carry that much current (marked in green), also what is this island marked in blue, seems like a not proper aligned fill.

